# Segmented Control not working as expected on Segment 0

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a segmented control that alters 5 images on one of my View Controllers (see image below) but I want Segment 0 to be selected straight away when someone goes into the Casting Tab. At present it only gets selected when i go onto either Segment 1 or 2 and then back, after that it obviously works as it should.

In the Attributes Inspector beside Behavior I have Enabled and Selected ticked, I have even tried State Selected ticked but always the same result so I'm unsure where I'm going wrong. I can get a visual fix by adding code to my ViewDidLoad for the 5 images, setting four of them to .isHidden = true and one to .isHidden = false but this doesn't solve my problem obviously.

Here is my code:

```
    import UIKit

        class CastingViewController: UIViewController {

            let runesArray = [Rune(runeName: "Fehu", runeImage: UIImage(named: ("Fehu.png"))!, runeDescription: "Description goes here."),
                              Rune(runeName: "Uruz", runeImage: UIImage(named: ("Uruz.png"))!, runeDescription: "Description goes here."),
                              Rune(runeName: "Thurisaz", runeImage: UIImage(named: ("Thurisaz.png"))!, runeDescription: "Description goes here."),
                              Rune(runeName: "Ansuz", runeImage: UIImage(named: ("Ansuz.png"))!, runeDescription: "Description goes here."),
                              Rune(runeName: "Raidho", runeImage: UIImage(named: ("Raidho.png"))!, runeDescription: "Description goes here."),
                              Rune(runeName: "Kenaz", runeImage: UIImage(named: ("Kenaz.png"))!, runeDescription: "Description goes here."),
                              Rune(runeName: "Gebo", runeImage: UIImage(named: ("Gebo.png"))!, runeDescription: "Description goes here."),
                              Rune(runeName: "Wunjo", runeImage: UIImage(named: ("Wunjo.png"))!, runeDescription: "Description goes here."),

                              Rune(runeName: "Hagalaz", runeImage: UIImage(named: ("Hagalaz.png"))!, runeDescription: "Description goes here."),
                              Rune(runeName: "Nauthiz", runeImage: UIImage(named: ("Nauthiz.png"))!, runeDescription: "Description goes here."),
                              Rune(runeName: "Isa", runeImage: UIImage(named: ("Isa.png"))!, runeDescription: "Description goes here."),
                              Rune(runeName: "Jera", runeImage: UIImage(named: ("Jera.png"))!, runeDescription: "Description goes here."),
                              Rune(runeName: "Eihwaz", runeImage: UIImage(named: ("Eihwaz.png"))!, runeDescription: "Description goes here."),
                              Rune(runeName: "Perthro", runeImage: UIImage(named: ("Perthro.png"))!, runeDescription: "Description goes here."),
                              Rune(runeName: "Algiz", runeImage: UIImage(named: ("Algiz.png"))!, runeDescription: "Description goes here."),
                              Rune(runeName: "Sowilo", runeImage: UIImage(named: ("Sowilo.png"))!, runeDescription: "Description goes here."),

                              Rune(runeName: "Tiwaz", runeImage: UIImage(named: ("Tiwaz.png"))!, runeDescription: "Description goes here."),
                              Rune(runeName: "Berkano", runeImage: UIImage(named: ("Berkano.png"))!, runeDescription: "Description goes here."),
                              Rune(runeName: "Ehwaz", runeImage: UIImage(named: ("Ehwaz.png"))!, runeDescription: "(Description goes here."),
                              Rune(runeName: "Mannaz", runeImage: UIImage(named: ("Mannaz.png"))!, runeDescription: "Description goes here."),
                              Rune(runeName: "Laguz", runeImage: UIImage(named: ("Laguz.png"))!, runeDescription: "Description goes here."),
                              Rune(runeName: "Ingwaz", runeImage: UIImage(named: ("Ingwaz.png"))!, runeDescription: "Description goes here."),
                              Rune(runeName: "Dagaz", runeImage: UIImage(named: ("Dagaz.png"))!, runeDescription: "Description goes here."),
                              Rune(runeName: "Othala", runeImage: UIImage(named: ("Othala.png"))!, runeDescription: "Description goes here.")]

            var runesCastArray: [UIImage] = [] // Array to save Rune images for 3 or 5 Rune Cast

    @IBOutlet weak var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var runeOne: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var runeTwo: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var runeThree: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var runeFour: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var runeFive: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
    }

    var runeCast = 0 // Need to check if this will work in a Switch statement

    var storedRuneOne: UIImage!
    var storedRuneTwo: UIImage!
    var storedRuneThree: UIImage!
    var storedRuneFour: UIImage!
    var storedRuneFive: UIImage!

    func oneRuneCast() {

        runeCast = 1
        runeOne.isHidden = true
        runeTwo.isHidden = true
        runeThree.isHidden = true
        runeFour.isHidden = true
        runeFive.isHidden = false

    }

    func threeRuneCast() {

        runeCast = 3
        runeOne.isHidden = true
        runeTwo.isHidden = false
        runeThree.isHidden = true
        runeFour.isHidden = false
        runeFive.isHidden = false

    }

    func fiveRuneCast() {

        runeCast = 5
        runeOne.isHidden = false
        runeTwo.isHidden = false
        runeThree.isHidden = false
        runeFour.isHidden = false
        runeFive.isHidden = false

    }

    @IBAction func castType(_ sender: Any) {

       switch segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0:
            oneRuneCast()
        case 1:
            threeRuneCast()
        case 2:
            fiveRuneCast()
        default: break
        }

    }

    @IBAction func castButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

        if runeCast == 1 {

        let randomRunes = runesArray[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(runesArray.count)))]

            runeFive.image = randomRunes.runeImage


        } else if runeCast == 3 {

            let randomRunes = runesArray[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(runesArray.count)))]

            runeTwo.image = randomRunes.runeImage
            runeFour.image = randomRunes.runeImage
            runeFive.image = randomRunes.runeImage

        } else if runeCast == 5 {

            let randomRunes = runesArray[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(runesArray.count)))]

            runeOne.image = randomRunes.runeImage
            runeTwo.image = randomRunes.runeImage
            runeThree.image = randomRunes.runeImage
            runeFour.image = randomRunes.runeImage
            runeFive.image = randomRunes.runeImage

            }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: The code that is in `castType` should be in another function that shows/hides the images as appropriate. You then call this function in `castType` and in `viewWillAppear`. When you set the selected segment programmatically, it does not trigger the `@IBAction` function

Comment: HI @Paulw11 i've updated my code above and still having the same outcome, I've tried segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0 in viewDidLoad, viewDidAppear & viewWillAppear and still the same outcome. Any other suggestions? many thanks

Comment: Now, just add a call to `oneRuneCast` in `viewWillAppear`.

Answer (score 3):

Programmatically set the segment index in the viewDidAppear or viewDidLoad (upto your application requirements)

```
override func viewDidAppear() {
        super.viewDidAppear()

        segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
}
```

Comment: when i read your answer i thought yes of course! that makes sense but i have tried both with no luck, still the same outcome for me.  My code above didn't have an outlet setup for the segmented control but once added and code changed to represent this i'm still getting the same outcome

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset the selected segment index when the view appears (say in `viewWillAppear`), but programatically changing the selected segment *does not* call the action handler; you need to call that explicitly.

You could also simplify your code by putting your `UIImageViews` in an array;

```
class CastingViewController: UIViewController {

            let runesArray = [Rune(runeName: "Fehu", runeImage: UIImage(named: ("Fehu.png"))!, runeDescription: "Description goes here."),
                              Rune(runeName: "Uruz", runeImage: UIImage(named: ("Uruz.png"))!, runeDescription: "Description goes here."),
                              Rune(runeName: "Thurisaz", runeImage: UIImage(named: ("Thurisaz.png"))!, runeDescription: "Description goes here."),
                              Rune(runeName: "Ansuz", runeImage: UIImage(named: ("Ansuz.png"))!, runeDescription: "Description goes here."),
                              Rune(runeName: "Raidho", runeImage: UIImage(named: ("Raidho.png"))!, runeDescription: "Description goes here."),
                              Rune(runeName: "Kenaz", runeImage: UIImage(named: ("Kenaz.png"))!, runeDescription: "Description goes here."),
                              Rune(runeName: "Gebo", runeImage: UIImage(named: ("Gebo.png"))!, runeDescription: "Description goes here."),
                              Rune(runeName: "Wunjo", runeImage: UIImage(named: ("Wunjo.png"))!, runeDescription: "Description goes here."),

                              Rune(runeName: "Hagalaz", runeImage: UIImage(named: ("Hagalaz.png"))!, runeDescription: "Description goes here."),
                              Rune(runeName: "Nauthiz", runeImage: UIImage(named: ("Nauthiz.png"))!, runeDescription: "Description goes here."),
                              Rune(runeName: "Isa", runeImage: UIImage(named: ("Isa.png"))!, runeDescription: "Description goes here."),
                              Rune(runeName: "Jera", runeImage: UIImage(named: ("Jera.png"))!, runeDescription: "Description goes here."),
                              Rune(runeName: "Eihwaz", runeImage: UIImage(named: ("Eihwaz.png"))!, runeDescription: "Description goes here."),
                              Rune(runeName: "Perthro", runeImage: UIImage(named: ("Perthro.png"))!, runeDescription: "Description goes here."),
                              Rune(runeName: "Algiz", runeImage: UIImage(named: ("Algiz.png"))!, runeDescription: "Description goes here."),
                              Rune(runeName: "Sowilo", runeImage: UIImage(named: ("Sowilo.png"))!, runeDescription: "Description goes here."),

                              Rune(runeName: "Tiwaz", runeImage: UIImage(named: ("Tiwaz.png"))!, runeDescription: "Description goes here."),
                              Rune(runeName: "Berkano", runeImage: UIImage(named: ("Berkano.png"))!, runeDescription: "Description goes here."),
                              Rune(runeName: "Ehwaz", runeImage: UIImage(named: ("Ehwaz.png"))!, runeDescription: "(Description goes here."),
                              Rune(runeName: "Mannaz", runeImage: UIImage(named: ("Mannaz.png"))!, runeDescription: "Description goes here."),
                              Rune(runeName: "Laguz", runeImage: UIImage(named: ("Laguz.png"))!, runeDescription: "Description goes here."),
                              Rune(runeName: "Ingwaz", runeImage: UIImage(named: ("Ingwaz.png"))!, runeDescription: "Description goes here."),
                              Rune(runeName: "Dagaz", runeImage: UIImage(named: ("Dagaz.png"))!, runeDescription: "Description goes here."),
                              Rune(runeName: "Othala", runeImage: UIImage(named: ("Othala.png"))!, runeDescription: "Description goes here.")]

            var runesCastArray: [UIImage] = [] // Array to save Rune images for 3 or 5 Rune Cast

    @IBOutlet weak var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var runeOne: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var runeTwo: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var runeThree: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var runeFour: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var runeFive: UIImageView!

    var runeImageViews:[UIImageView]!
    var runeCount = 1

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        self.runeImageViews=[runeFive,runeFour,runeThree,runeTwo,runeOne]

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
        self.runeCount = 1
        self.showHideRuneViews()
    }

    func showHideRuneViews(clearImage: Bool=true) {
        for i in 0..<self.runeImageViews.count {
            let imageView = self.runeImageViews[i]
            if i < self.runeCount {
                imageView.isHidden = false
            } else {
                imageView.isHidden = true
            }
            if clearImage {
                imageView.image = nil
            }
        }
    }

    func runeCast() {
        for i in 0..<self.runeImageViews.count.reversed() {
            let imageView = self.runeImageViews[i]
            if i < self.runeCount {
                 imageView.image = runesArray[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(runesArray.count)))]
            } else {
                  imageView.image = nil
        }
    }

    @IBAction func castType(_ sender: Any) {

       switch segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0:
            self.runeCount = 1
        case 1:
            self.runeCount = 3
        case 2:
            self.runeCount = 5
        default: break
        }

        self.showHideRuneViews()

    }

    @IBAction func castButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        self.runeCast()
    }
}
```